# Append a php variable at top of php file after the <?php open tag

Tags: php, file

i need to write a php variable at the top of php file after the php tah(

```
<?php
   $test = "this is a string";       
?>
After appending the variable, the above content shoud be like,
<?php
   $subscriptionId = "123456789";
   $test = "this is a string";
?>
 Could not make it work using fwrite. Please suggest solution
```

Comment: You can write the complete file again not by appending only

Comment: well, is there any other solution besides writing the file completely again.....?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope you're not describing an editor usage problem. Otherwise I'd recommend a regular expression to achieve the insertion:

```
$php = file_get_contents("example.php");
$php = preg_replace("/(<[?]php\s+)/", '$1  $subscriptionId = "123";\n', $php);
file_put_contents("example.php", $php);
```

There's no filesystem function for in-place insertion. You can only completely overwrite the php script.

Comment: thank you so much, i was looking for this solution, have a great day

Answer (score 2):

Use str_replace() and don't omit to set the 4th parameter to 1, otherwise all occurrences of "`<?php`" will be replaced:

```
$php = file_get_contents("example.php");
$php = str_replace("<?php", "<?php\n  $subscriptionId = \"123456789\";\n", $php, 1);
file_put_contents("example.php", $php);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it at the webserver level, there's the php.ini [`auto_prepend_file`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php) parameter. With some judicious <File>/<Location> setup in a httpd.conf file, you can limit which .php files have this parameter applied.